# Communication between components and routes in emberjs 2.0?

Tags: ember.js

I have two models in my route, people and appointments.

My components are:
people-list(parent) and people items(children),
appointment-list(parent) and appointment items(children).

In my route, I want to list appointments based on checked people (checkboxes in each people item). How would I tell my route about all the checked people items?

Also, I have a datepicker on the route, I want to display appointments based on date, how would I go about doing this?

Again, I want to use pure COMPONENTS, no controllers and I also do not want to make a property in my people model called isChecked as this would never be a real attribute in a real database table.

Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How does your route URL look like?

Comment: it is simply /appointments. anything more specific?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's counter-productive to avoid controllers completely, as what you describe is one of the things that controllers are about, holding on to state.

The route is responsible for dealing with the URL segments of the application and setting up the template/controller/model combo, but it doesn't know anything about them, so it'd be a bad place to keep that data in.

An alternative is to use a service, which is possibly trickier than relying on the controller.

What you should avoid is the proxying behaviour of the old `ObjectController` and `ArrayController` (gone in 2.0), and don't rely on the controller being a singleton (routable components won't be singletons).

Comment: I will see what to do, most likely I will just attach a property on the model that won't persist to the database and throw the model around as I see fit.